# How to get state data right after changing them from parent to child in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react app with several components. I have two child components (card and modal) and one parent component (board). Simply I'm clicking on a card in card component and send the card ID to the board component. Board component has API data. It filters the API data with the card ID coming from card component and show the relevant data in modal component.

**The problem is, modal component loads an empty array which is projectData at the beginning even before clicking on a card. Then I can't get any element inside the array and says "Can't get property undefined" for each array call.**

Card component:

```
class TaskItem extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      more_state: false
    }
  }

  render() {

    const { sendCardId } = this.props;

    return(
      <div onClick={() => sendCardId(task.projectID)}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Board component:

```
class Taskboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentID: null,
      projectAllData: [],
      open: false,
    };
  }

  getPojectId = (projectId) => {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
      currentId: projectId
    });

    API.get('project/' + projectId)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          projectAllData: data.response
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ProjectModal
          handleOpen={this.state.open}
          handleClosed={this.handleClose}
          projectID={this.state.currentId}
          projectData={this.state.projectAllData}
        />

      <Column
        key={key}
        index={index}
        title={key}
        tasks={columns[key]}
        getCardId={this.getPojectId}
       />
    )
  }
}
```

Modal component:

```
class ProjectModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            status: 'To do',
        };
    }

    render(){

      const { handleOpen, handleClosed, projectData, projectID } = this.props;
      return(
         <div>{projectData.projectName}</div
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidJohns As Tholle said, you have to modify state `projectAllData` array to object include `projectName`.

Comment: @kkangil the thing is I'm getting the projectName after clicking twice on a card which means the state is updating on the second time

Comment: where is your click function that get `projectName ` result? The `getPojectId` function with axios gets the `projectName` result but you don't use anywhere above code.

Comment: @kkangil you can see the `onclick` method in a div in Card component. It fires the `sendCardId` method with project id and catch it in board component with `getProjectId` method. It will call API and send all the project data including `projectName` to modal component.

Comment: @DavidJohns ok but the projectAllData doesn't have `projectName`, it's array. why do you call setState twice in getPojectId? just use once.

Comment: @kkangil So, do I need to create an empty array first?

Comment: @DavidJohns what about try to check below code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setState once.

```
getPojectId = (projectId) => {
    API.get('project/' + projectId)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          projectAllData: data.response,
          open: true,
          currentId: projectId
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
  }
```

And set init state object not array

```
this.state = {
      currentID: null,
      projectAllData: {projectName: ''},
      open: false,
    };
```

or This might be better.

```
this.state = {
  currentID: null,
  projectAllData: undefined,
  open: false,
};
render(){
  return(
    <>
    {
      this.state.projectAllData && (
        <ProjectModal
          handleOpen={this.state.open}
          handleClosed={this.handleClose}
          projectID={this.state.currentId}
          projectData={this.state.projectAllData}
        />
      )
    }

    <Column
      key={key}
      index={index}
      title={key}
      tasks={columns[key]}
      getCardId={this.getPojectId}
      />
    </>
  )
```